# default noexcept move semantics

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, move-semantics, noexcept

I'm having trouble understanding the reason behind the following error.

Example code:

```
#include <string>

class Message {
private:
  std::string from;
  std::string to;
  std::string message;

public:
  Message() = default;
  Message(Message&&) noexcept = default;
  Message(const Message&) = default;
  Message& operator=(Message&&) noexcept = default;
  Message& operator=(const Message&) = default;

  Message(const std::string& from,
          const std::string& to,
          const std::string& message)
    : from(from),
      to(to),
      message(message)
  { }

  std::string getFrom() const { return from; }
  std::string getTo() const { return to; }
  std::string getMessage() const { return message; }
};

int main() {
  Message m("me", "you", "hello");
  return 0;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall noexcept.cpp 
noexcept.cpp:13:12: error: function ‘Message& Message::operator=(Message&&)’ defaulted on its first declaration with an exception-specification that differs from the implicit declaration ‘Message& Message::operator=(Message&&)’
   Message& operator=(Message&&) noexcept = default;
```

Compiler version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Simply removing *noexcept* from the default move assignment operator allows the example to compile.  But I don't understand why the default move constructor allows *noexcept* yet the default move assignment operator does not.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: g++ 4.8 was pretty still implementing C++11.  Running your code on a [current version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36a62f4100b75167) produces no errors.  I'm going to say it is a bug that has been fixed or support that was just not complete yet.

Comment: that was fixed in 4.9

Comment: Verified.  I built g++ 5.4 and it doesn't have the problem.

But it's interesting to note that clang 3.8 has the exact same problem.  Perhaps it has something to do with the C++11 standard?

Comment: Here is the clang error output for reference:

    $ clang++-3.8 -std=c++11 -Wall noexcept.cpp 
    noexcept.cpp:13:12: error: exception specification of explicitly defaulted move assignment operator does not match
          the calculated one
      Message& operator=(Message&&) noexcept = default;
               ^
    1 error generated.